# Which approach is correct?

Tags: linear-algebra

Find an augmented matrix with non-zero entries whose system
$$
\begin{align*}
ax + by &= c   \\
dx + ey &= f 
\end{align*}
$$
has

1. no solutions,
2. exactly one solution,
3. infinitely many solutions.

I'm considering firstly change the matrix into reduced echelon form using $a,b,c,d,e,f$ to represent. So I get $ea=bd$ and $fa\neq cd$ for no solutions. I'm sure whether I'm on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Gaussian method and do row reduction, then at the end of the process you do an analysis on the equation of the form $ax = b$ and analyze the different cases.

Indeed, note that $$(S.E.L): \left\{\begin{aligned} ax+by=c\\ 
 dx+ey=f  \end{aligned} \right. \iff  \begin{pmatrix} a & b & | & c \\ d & e & | & f \end{pmatrix}\sim \begin{pmatrix} a & b & | & c \\ 0 & \frac{-bd+ae}{a} & | & \frac{-cd+af}{a}\end{pmatrix} $$
Now,

1. The S.E.L doesn't have solution if $$ \frac{-bd+ae}{a}=0 \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{-cd+af}{a}\not=0$$
2. The S.E.L exactly one solution if $$\frac{-bd+ae}{a}\not=0 \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{-cd+af}{a}\not=0$$
3. The S.E.L have infinitely many solution if $$\frac{-bd+ae}{a}=0 \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{-cd+af}{a}=0$$

Answer (score 0):

1. $$\begin{cases}x+y=1,\\x+y=2\end{cases}$$
   (impossible because $1\ne2$)
2. $$\begin{cases}x+y=1,\\x+2y=1\end{cases}$$
   (equivalent to $\begin{cases}x+y=1,\\\ \ \ \ \ \ \ y=0\end{cases}$)
3. $$\begin{cases}x+y=1,\\x+y=1\end{cases}$$
   (indeterminate because the equations are the same)